# Divs to next to each other

Tags: html, css-float

See this link:
http://clients.noxxie.nl/spelletjesportal/

I have tried everything but how can I put the 3 boxes (totally white) next to each other?

Would help me allot!

Comment: For future visitors, it's usually better to paste the code and maybe a picture of the outcome also here in your question. The link you provided may be quite volatile, i.e. in a week, it might be a dead link and this question would be useless...

Answer (score 1):

`.box` has a `clear: both` on it... you need to override that with `clear: none;` on `.box.games`

Answer (score 0):

Your css declaration for .box contains `clear: both`. Remove it or have `clear: none` in the .box.games declaration.